# Weighted Least Squares Normalization for Parameter Uncertainty

Tags: least-squares, normalization, weighted-regression

I want to fit a function $f(x_1,x_2..)$ to (noisy) data with unknown variance. For each datapoint, I have a weight $w_i$ which is proportional to the reliability of that particular datapoint. The real uncertainty of the datapoints is unknown.
I do the fitting using Matlab and Levenberg-Marquardt so that I end up with the parameter estimates $\hat{\beta}$ and the Jacobian $J$. I calculate the variance of the parameter estimates as follows:
$$\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{RSS}{n-p+1} \cdot (J'WJ)^{-1}$$ 
Where $W$ is the diagonal matrix of the weights, $n$ is the number of datapoints and $p$ is the degrees of freedom.

My question is regarding the normalization of the weights and it's effect on the parameter uncertainty, since I have seen some conflicting definitions and opinions on this subject.

**Question**: How do I normalize my weights so that the calculated parameter standard errors are meaningful?
I currently normalize the weights so that their sum is the number of datapoints $N$, similar to non-weighted least squares: $\Sigma w_i = N$. Is this correct?